# iter storage in substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I Wanna to create a StoreBasket in Substrate .

I Have Two `Struct` one for `BusinessItem` .

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
#[codec(mel_bound())]
pub struct BusinessItem {
    media: Vec<u8>,
    title: Vec<u8>,
    description: Vec<u8>,
    price: u32,
    count: u32,
    itemId: [u8; 16],
}
```

also i Defined Storage For Item:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn items)]
pub(super) type Items<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::AccountId, Vec<BusinessItem>>;
```

I wanna to find item in item Storage with itemid , for exmaple i have itemId : `X0o788dfgg` and i need to find item with this id in storage .

i wrote this code bit it dose not work :

```
let _itemInfo: Option<&BusinessItem> = items.iter().find(|item| item.itemId == item_id);
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: Why is this not a `StorageDoubleMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

[`IterableStorageMap` doc](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/trait.IterableStorageMap.html).

```rs
if let Some(item) = <Items<T>>::iter().find(|(_, i)| i.id == id) {
  log::info!("got {:#?}", item);
}
```

But I don't recommend using this. Because it will do a lot of r/w, which costs a lot of resources.

Maybe you should add another map to record the mapping `ItemId -> AccountId`. Or something like that.

---

Okay, I found you are trying to store a `Vec<Item>` under each `AccountId` key. I have to say, this has a really bad performance.

```rs
let mut matched_items = Vec::new();
<Items<T>>::iter().for_each(|(_, items)| {
  items.iter().for_each(|i| {
    if i.id == id {
      matched_items.push(i.clone());
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: it show me this error : ` no field `itemId` on type `&&frame_support::dispatch::Vec<BusinessItem>``

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake here. Let me update my answer.

Comment: thanks for answer but still show me error : ` no field `itemId` on type `&(<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, frame_support::dispatch::Vec<BusinessItem>)``

Comment: Sry, try this `find(|(_, i)| i.id == id)`. Because the iterator returns a tuple `(K, V)`.

Comment: no field `itemId` on type `&frame_support::dispatch::Vec<BusinessItem>`

Comment: Okay. I know. Your storage item is a `Vec<Item>`. Is this what you expect?

Comment: i except find item in the vec

Comment: Try the latest code.